# For loops and appending to a numpy array

Tags: python

```
def drag_polar(B, Re, alpha_max=4):
    alphas = np.linspace(0, alpha_max, 17)
    cls = np.zeros(len(alphas))
    cds = np.zeros(len(alphas))
    for i in range(len(alphas)):
        cls[i], cds[i], xl, xu, cpl, cpu = airfoilsim(B, alpha[i], Re)
    return alphas, cls, cds
```

I am trying to use a for loop to fill the numpy arrays of cls and CDs with their respective values but for some reason it is not working. Can anyone spot what is wrong with this?

Comment: what is B and Re

Comment: what output do you expect, and what do you get?

Comment: What do you mean not working? What's the expected behavior and what do you observe that's inconsistent with the expectation?

Comment: should `alpha[i]` be `alphas[i]`? can you show example return value of the `airfoilsim` function?

Comment: What is not working? Did you get any error?

Comment: Thanks, Stuart the problem was it should have been alphas[I], not alpha[i].